# Script that open an url then close the browser

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script that need to do the following task :

- Open an url then close the windows that got open

```
Start-Process -FilePath msedge http://127.0.0.1:62354/now
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
get-process msedge | %{ $_.closemainwindow() }
```

I'm facing 2 issues :

-First one : is I actually force to open the url with Edge so I could close it without any issue for knowing what default browser the user may use.

-Second one : When I close the window it's actually close all Edge process instead of the one that just got open which is troublesome since user may also use this browser to work on webapp

The first one would not be an issue if I could solve the second issue honestly

Hope you guys can help me

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Julia I use a solution to do an inventory for my asset in my internship and I need to deploy agent on every asset then force the agent to contact the main server with the url http://127.0.0.1:62354/now and since I don't want to bother user with a browser that open and make them close it  , I would like to close it with the script. The solution is GLPI if you happen to know it

Comment: Do you have to use MS Edge? Probably you could try a "chrome.sessions".

Comment: @harper Hi , no I don't need to use Edge but since I was sure it was by default on each asset , I said to myselft instead of check every default browser let's just use Edge instead , how should i use chrome.sessions then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it like this, when you open internet explorer, edge or chrome and browse to a URL, it sends an `HTTP GET` to the URL, which responds with an html file.  It then does a `GET` for each script and file embedded on the page.

All you want to do is load this page for a second so you can register it on some server.

With that in mind, **you don't really need to** browse to this webpage, you could just send a webrequest instead.

Try this instead!

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://127.0.0.1:62354/now
```

Comment: A huge thanks for your answer , not only you gave the solution but you explained the reason behind it. thanks a lot.  NB: I tried it and worked fine for me